# Ethernet port sleeping on PS3 running linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

My lab has a PS3 running Ubuntu Linux 9.04 Server Edition. After a period of a few hours with no use, the Ethernet connection (eth0) seems to go to sleep, causing the connection to be lost. Pinging or trying to SSH into the machine results in no response. The fix I've been using is to access the machine locally and restart it (trying to bring eth0 down then up doesn't seem to correct it).

I've tried setting up an hourly cron job that runs on the PS3 and pings another machine just to create network activity, but this doesn't seem to solve the problem either.

---

**Update:** The solution was to run the above cron job much more frequently: every 10 minutes works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't own one, so for this answer, YMMV.  However, it appears that the PS3 implements some portion of [802.3az](http://www.ieee802.org/3/az/index.html), which appears to be related to your issue.

Rather than sending pings from outside of your PS3 unit, you should send it from the PS3 itself.  This will tickle the network stack - and (hopefully) the ethernet port - to make it "busy", averting the dreaded sleep.

Comment: The cron job is on the PS3 and it pings another machine on the network. I'll update my question to make that point clearer.

Comment: This is the solution, only the ping needs to run much more frequently than every hour. Right now, mine is running every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you using NetworkManager try switching back to old networking without NetworkManager. That might solve the problem.

Comment: This is the server install, so NetworkManager is not used.